# Accumulating return value from each function in a function array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

*I've tried searching for this, but without much success so that leads me to ask the question here. Feel free to link me to a duplicate if this has been asked before.*

I have an array of functions with an unknown (n) size. I would like to call all the methods and then accumulate the result of each function. I know this can be done using both `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.reduce` like so:

```js
const arr = [
    () => 4,
    () => 5,
    () => 2,
];

const result = arr
    .map((f) => f())
    .reduce((acc, next) => acc + next);
// result = 11
```

This is of course already a quite clean solution, but I was wondering if there was a cleaner one using a single array method. Preferably a native method and maybe even one that can be passed with a custom type if used with typescript.

Comment: What is it you want to achieve with the types? Somehow combining the return types of all of the functions?

Comment: Just use reduce without needing to map first? Something like `arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with just reduce:

```js
arr.reduce((acc, next) => acc + next(), 0)
```

Comment: I, for some reason, hadn't realized that I could just have passed the initialValue parameter, even though I've actually done that multiple times before, now that I think of it. I feel a bit silly now. But regardless, it works. Thank you!